# Using grep to find all lines containing a character on an even position

Tags: bash, command-line, grep, regular-expression

So a line in the text file looks like this:

```
......-...-..--- (hello)
```

I want to find all lines that only have dots on the even positions. So I think I need to repeat searching for the regex pattern `.\.` which allows any character on the first position and requires a dot as the second one.

I don't know, however, how to keep looking for this pattern until a space followed by parentheses is found.

The following output would be correct:

```
....-. (word)
-.-.-.. (word)
-.-.....-.-. (word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for *any* character on odd positions, simply only look for the *legal* characters (your dit, `\.` and your dah, `-`, I guess?). The regex way of expressing "any of this set of characters" is `[…]`, i.e., your elementary pattern becomes `[\.-]\.`.

By the way, without spaces between the letters in your morse code, it's impossible to unambigously interpret the morse code. (Morse is not a *prefix-free* code; encoded letters can be the found at the beginning of other letters.) So, I think your examples are kind of broken; you will need to insert spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what I'm trying to do is find the lines which only contain dits/dots on even places. However, I don't know how to write an regex that looks for a repeated pattern. I basically need a regex that looks for the pattern of "either dot or dash followed by a dot" repeated throughout the line.